# Task MyFunctionAsync() calling Task<T> AnotherFunctionAsync()

Tags: c#, async-await

This might be a bit difficult to illustrate but I'll try.  Assembly `Foo` calls into Assembly `Bar`.  Assembly `Bar` has a NuGet package installed it uses to gain access to certain model classes and interact with a remote API.  Inside assembly `Bar` is a class `Helper` containing a method with the following signature:

```cs
Task GetSomeDataAsync(string id);
```

`GetSomeDataAsync()` calls into the NuGet package which is fully asynchronous.

```cs
async Task Helper.GetSomeDataAsync(string id)
{
   var api = new ApiFromNuGet();
   ResultObjectFromNuGet result = await api.GetInstanceAsync(id);
   ...
   // Do a bunch of stuff with no more async calls.
}
```

Now assembly `Foo` does not have the NuGet package installed nor can it be installed. Not my code, not my business rules.  Think of it as a UI layer calling into a ViewModel that calls into a Repository.  You don't want to reference the Repository from the UI.  Assembly `Foo` has a method with the following signature:

```cs
Task ProcessRequestAsync(string id);
```

Inside `ProcessRequestAsync()` it does the following:

```cs
async Task ProcessRequestAsync(string id)
{
   Bar.Helper helper = new Bar.Helper();
   await helper.GetSomeDataAsync(id);
   ...
}
```

What's happening is the `Foo` assembly fails to compile. The compiler is generating an error that the NuGet package referenced in the `Bar` assembly needs to be installed because it's referencing a type in the assembly. Makes sense.

I tried to change `GetSomeDataAsync()` to

```cs
Task Helper.GetSomeDataAsync(string id)
{
   var api = new ApiFromNuget();
   ResultObjectFromNuGet result = api.GetInstanceAsync(id).Result();
   ...
   // Do a bunch of stuff with no more async calls.
   return Task.CompletedResult;
}
```

Nope. No luck. The only thing I've been able to get compiled is to change `GetSomeDataAsync()` to return `void`. Which would then force the call stack above to change to deal with a `void` return type instead of a `Task`. Which seems like a code smell to me.  I'm sure there's a better approach to hide the `Task<ResultObjectFromNuget>` that's being returned to simply a `Task`.

==== UPDATE =====
Target framework from the few projects I checked is .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the target frameworks of the mentioned assemblies (e.g. .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard)?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the build order?

Comment: @Grizzlly I doubt it.  `await Bar.DoSomethingAsync()` is a `Task<ResultObjectFromNuGet>` and simply returning a `Task` doesn't change that since `Task<T>` is a `Task`. What doesn't make sense is why essentially changing the function to synchronous and returning a `Task.CompletedTask` doesn't make the compilation error go away.

Comment: @BTSoft What if you return `Task.FromResult()`? What is the compilation error exactly? It does not matter what type of method you have. You are still using the package.

Comment: @Grizzlly Since the return type of `ApiFromNuGet.GetInstanceAsync()` is an `ObjectResultFromNuGet`, using `Task.FromResult()` is going to return a `Task<ObjectResultFromNuGet>` which it already does.  Which is not what I (a) want or (b) need in `Foo`.  The `Foo` assembly never uses the result.